# Use Postgres features like JSON functions in Laravel

Tags: php, json, postgresql, laravel, eloquent

Postgresql has some function and operations for using JSON data. As it describes in [postgresql site](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html), it's possible to save JSON data in a column and get JSON array element with **->** operator. Everything is ok in 
plain php, but I want to use it on Laravel framework and specially with [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent) or [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries).

Is there any standard solution for this functionality in Laravel? I developed plain sql like bellow code and it works but I'm looking for a better solution.

```
$host = env('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
$database = env('DB_DATABASE', 'aaa');
$user = env('DB_USERNAME', '22222');
$pass = env('DB_PASSWORD', '11111');
$table = 'table';
$column = 'json';
$connection = pg_connect("host=$host dbname=$database user=$user password=$pass");
$result = pg_fetch_all(pg_query($connection, "SELECT $column->>'name' FROM \"$table\" "));
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Laravel 5.3, this is possible, but only for MySQL. Version 5.6 supports also Postgress. Assume you have the following user with profile as JSON datatype:

```
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Mahmood",
    "profile": {
        "bio": "Lorem ipsum",
        "phone": "1234"
    }
```

You can query as such:

```
$phone = DB::table('users')
    ->where('profile->phone', '1234')
    ->get();
```

Reference: https://mattstauffer.co/blog/new-json-column-where-and-update-syntax-in-laravel-5-3

Comment: "Note: MariaDB does not have JSON columns, and PostgreSQL has JSON columns but this feature appears to not currently work on them. So consider this a MySQL 5.7+ feature for now." - according to your link

Comment: I have digged deeper, version 5.3 doesn't support Postgress, but apparently version 5.6 does.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't currently supported in Laravel. You can see SQL grammar unique to Postgresql support in Laravel [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/PostgresGrammar.php).

You can however use [raw statements](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#running-queries) with Eloquent, which should handle what you need.